# Como mostrar div según sea el valor en una variable de PHP

Tags: javascript, php, div

Estoy intentando mostrar un `div` el cual contiene un input para carga de archivos, la regla que requiero cumplir es mostrar el `div` solo si el estatus es igual a 1 de lo contrario lo va a ocultar.

El estatus lo tengo declarado en una variable en PHP llamada `$estatus`, para ocultar el div uso la propiedad `display='none'`.

El siguiente es el código de validación que utilizo en una función en Javascript.

```
function showFileInput (){
    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    if ($estatus == '1'){
        element.style.display='block';
    }else{
        element.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

En mi código HTML tengo el siguiente `div` que deseo mostrar cuando el estatus sea igual a 1.

```
<div id="content" class="form-group row">
                <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File Upload:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidateFile()" required="">
              </div>
          </div>
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que hago uso del evento `onchange` para otras validaciones adicionales que utilizo al cargar el archivo.

Con lo que tengo previamente aún no se oculta el div cuando el estatus es diferente a 1, se sigue mostrando, ¿Hay algo que este haciendo mal en mi validación o me haga falta adicional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo directamente en tu vista sin javascript, aqui tienes que ver si esta opción te serviría y no te afecte.

```
<?php if($variable==1)
echo "<div class='contenedor'>
...
</div>";
?>
```

Esto solo se agregara al html si cumple la condición.

O tambien

```
<div class='contendor' <?php if($variable==1) echo "style='display:block'"; else echo "style='display:none'"; ?> >
...
</div>
```

Comment: Posiblemente exista un error de sintaxis con el segundo ejemplo donde agrego la validación dentro del html, me sale el siguiente mensaje sobre el else `Unexpected 'else'. Expected ';'.`, ¿Hay alguna modificación que deba tener en cuenta?

Comment: A perdon no me percaté bien, la costumbre ya te lo modifico

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser así

```
function showFileInput (){
    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    if ('<?php echo $estatus; ?>' == '1'){
        element.style.display='block';
    }else{
        element.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

para cargar el valor de la variable de php.

O sin usar la función

```
<div class='contendor' <?php echo $variable==1?"style='display:block'":"style='display:none'" ?> >
...
</div>
```

Comment: Al parecer hay un error de sintaxis en el valor de la variable php, me indica que se esperaba una declaración o instrucción, ¿Hay alguna modificación adicional que se deba tener en cuenta?

Comment: Poner entre comillas sencillas las etiquetas de código php, porque se comparan caracteres.

Comment: Sigue sin aplicarse la validación, ¿ Hay algo mas que deba tener en cuenta? ¿En donde hago uso de la función `showFileInput` dentro de mi código HTML?

Comment: En `<body onload="showFileInput()">` o la segunda opción de la respuesta de @heyner-martinez también es mejor y más sencilla pues no requiere el uso de la función.